# Bower dependency version conflict

Tags: angularjs, bower

I am getting started for a angular project and am using bower.
I have installed two packages with --save to put them in bower.json.
When I run `bower update` I get this:

```
Please note that,
    ng-token-auth#0.0.29 depends on angular#>=1.4 <=1.5.3 which resolved to angular#1.5.3
    angular-animate#1.5.8, angular-aria#1.5.8, angular-loader#1.5.8, angular-messages#1.5.8, angular-mocks#1.5.8, angular-route#1.5.8 depends on angular#1.5.8 which resolved to angular#1.5.8
    angular-seed depends on angular#~1.5.0 which resolved to angular#1.5.8
    angular-material#1.0.9 depends on angular#^1.4.8 which resolved to angular#1.5.8
    angular-cookie#4.1.0 depends on angular#* which resolved to angular#1.5.8
Resort to using angular#>=1.4 <=1.5.3 which resolved to angular#1.5.3
Code incompatibilities may occur.
```

What should I do ?
This happened after adding ng-token-auth using `bower install ng-token-auth --save`.
My understanding is that

```
angular-animate#1.5.8, angular-aria#1.5.8, angular-loader#1.5.8, angular-messages#1.5.8, angular-mocks#1.5.8, angular-route#1.5.8
```

these are currently at 1.5.8, if these along with angular is at 1.5.3 my issue will be resolved, as these packages I believe are in tandem with angular.
Is my assumption correct?
I tried uninstalling all packages and then `bower install` but it made no difference.

Comment: Simple, `ng-token-auth` does not support Angular over 1.5.3. You can downgrade to that or try forcing 1.5.8 which will *probably* work

Comment: I added angular 1.5.3 to resolutions...but problem is angular-aria, angular-route these specifically are requiring 1.5.8...so their dependency is then unsatisfied... @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, `ng-token-auth` does not support Angular over 1.5.3. You can downgrade to that

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.3",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.3",
    ...
},
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.3"
}
```

or try forcing 1.5.8 which will *probably* work by using the [resolutions](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md#resolutions) config

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.8"
}
```

Comment: I don't wan't to force version 1.5.8 as I believe it might cause issue to ng-token-auth...Is there other way?

Comment: Thanks! I guess that will work...but since `angular-` packages must all have same version...why is it letting them get to 1.5.8 when angular itself is limited to 1.5.3 by ng-token-auth's requirement...just a doubt... @Phil